# How can I select the last row of a table with a matched class?

Tags: css

I'd like to put a divider on tables based on the last row to have a class. Table-rows are ordered by this class so it would make sense for me to put the divider on the last row to have that class. I can't seem to nail down the css for that though.

Here is my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kruser/cr9hLg9r/

Sample css

```
tbody>tr>td {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}

tbody>tr.boy:last-of-type>td {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so my previous answer was wrong, but I've got another idea. You could use a simple trick like this:

```css
table {
    border-collapse:collapse
}

tr {
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
}

.girl {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6ceom4u6/

**EDIT:**

OK, so I have another solution:

```css
table {
    border-collapse:collapse
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}

tr {
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
}

.boy + :not(.boy),
.girl + :not(.girl),
... {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6ceom4u6/4/

Comment: Very creative. I'd use if it in reality I only had two classes to worry about. In fact, I have 4+ groups each time.

Answer (score 2):

CSS does not have a `:last-of-other-combination-of-selectors` selector, so you can't do this with plain CSS.

It sounds like you would be better off restricting the markup to wrap your `tr` elements in explicit `tbody` elements, and then placing the border around the `tbody`s.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It cleared up my misunderstanding of the last* qualifiers.